# Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem from RCA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]
Hello!

This theorem from Rudin's RCA book. I would like to clarify some moments:

$1)$ Since $\limsup\limits_{n} v_n\leqslant 0$ where $v_n=\int \limits_{X}|f_n-f|d\mu$. We get $0\leqslant \liminf\limits_{n} v_n \leqslant\limsup\limits_{n} v_n\leqslant 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\liminf\limits_{n} v_n =\limsup\limits_{n} v_n=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}v_n=0$ i.e. $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int \limits_{X}|f_n-f|d\mu=0$.

$2)$ Since $|f_n-f|\leqslant 2g$ and $g\in L^1(\mu)$ then $f_n-f$ also in $L^1(\mu)$. Am I right? Since $\left|\int \limits_{X}(f_n-f)d\mu\right|\leqslant \int \limits_{X}|f_n-f|d\mu$ and since RHS of last inequality tends to zero then $$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int \limits_{X}(f_n-f)d\mu=0$$ since $f_n-f\in L^1(\mu)$ then by **theorem** $1.32$ we have $\int \limits_{X}(f_n-f)d\mu=\int \limits_{X}f_nd\mu-\int \limits_{X}fd\mu$ then $$\int \limits_{X}f_nd\mu\to\int \limits_{X}fd\mu$$ as $n\to \infty$.

Are my reasonings correct? Would be grateful for answer/comment.

Comment: Yes, your reasoning looks correct to me.

Comment: @kccu, Thanks a lot for checking!

Comment: Yes, I think the reasoning is totally correct.